# CDT on OS X Error: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, macos, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to create a C++ project using Eclipse CDT on OS X using the following steps:

1. Select **File** -> **New C++ Project**
2. Select **Executable** -> Hello World C++ Project
3. Set **Toolchains**: MacOSX GCC
4. Set **Project Name**: MyC++
5. Accept defaults for other values.

However, the error window shows:

- Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved
- Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved
- Symbol 'std' could not be resolved

My environment specifics:

- OS X 10.9.5
- Eclipse CDT 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I downloaded and used [Netbeans 8.0.2 C and C++ Development](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) which worked ok straight out of the box.